How to increase fetch size to reduce number of network calls while scanning a Cassandra table?
I am using datastax java driver version 4.15. I have read the paging documentation.
My application.conf looks like below
datastax-java-driver {   
    basic.contact-points = [ "<IP>:<PORT>"]
    basic.request {
      consistency = LOCAL_QUORUM
      page-size = 5000
    }
    advanced.prepared-statements {
      prepare-on-all-nodes = false
    }
  }

My scanning looks like below
ByteBuffer scan() {
  val query = "SELECT workflow_id, trace_id, message_key, created_at FROM workflow_message";
  val stmtBuilder = new SimpleStatementBuilder(query).setPageSize(5000);
  if (pagingState != null) {
      stmtBuilder.setPagingState(pagingState);
  }
   val rs = cqlSession.execute(stmtBuilder.build());
   while(rs.getAvailableWithoutFetching() > 0) {
    val row = rs.one();
    System.out.printf("\n%s, %s, %s", row.getString("workflow_id"), row.getString("trace_id"), row.getString("message_key"))
   }
   return rs.getExecutionInfo().getPagingState();
}

I am observing that about 25 rows are being read in a fetch. Can someone let me know how to increase the fetch size to reduce the number of network calls made to the server?

The basic.request.page-size is the correct option for setting the fetch size for queries. Just be aware that calling setPageSize() overrides the value set in the configuration file.
I should point out that an unbounded/unfiltered query (no WHERE clause) is a full table scan which does not scale. Unbounded queries can be unpredictable as either (a) the data size grows, (b) the cluster size grows, or both.
In any case, you can test the behaviour of the query using cqlsh with both CONSISTENCY and LIMIT set. Although cqlsh uses an embedded version of the Python driver, it's behaviour is identical to the Java driver when it comes to paging. Cheers!

Yes I am scanning a table. I have set page-size and also setPageSize to the same value 5000. But I am observing they are not taking effect and in a single fetch about 25 rows are being fetched. Do I have to change anything on the serve side for server to return that many result?

Paging is a client-side feature so there's nothing to set on the server side. I'd be interested to know whether you've actually tested the query with cqlsh as I've suggested. Cheers!

I executed the query  select workflow_id, trace_id, message_key from workflow_message LIMIT 5000; from cqlsh as suggested. I am observing that it is returning 100 and showing --MORE.
